# Large JN-sets in Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

For every infinite-dimensional Banach space $X$ there is a weak*-null sequence in the unit sphere of $X^\ast$. Does this extend under suitable circumstances to the non-separable setting?

Say that $X$ is a Banach space such that the unit ball of $X^\ast$ has weak*-density $\kappa$. Is there a family $f_\alpha$ ($\alpha<\kappa)$ in the unit sphere of $X^\ast$ such that for each $x\in X$ the function $\alpha \mapsto \langle f_\alpha, x\rangle$ belongs to $c_0(\kappa)$?

Comment: Let me add that the property holds for the duals of reflexive spaces and more generally for the duals of $WCG$ spaces. Also remains valid for $l^{\infty}(\Gamma) $ and its dual.

Answer (score 2):

A related question was asked by P. Holický, M. Šmídek, and L. Zajíček in [this paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/CMUC/pdf/cmuc9803/holicky.pdf) (Question 3). I have learnt from P. Koszmider and P. Hájek that the answer to this (and your) question is negative. See Example 2.16 (the space is of the form $C(K)$):

> A. Dow, H. Junnila and J. Pelant, [Chain conditions and weak topologies](https://Chain%20conditions%20and%20weak%20topologies), Topology Appl. 156 (2009), 1327–1344.

For a more Banach-space theoretic exposition please consult

> L. Candido, P. Koszmider, [On complemented copies of $c_0(\omega_1)$ in $C(K^n)$-spaces](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-doi-10_4064-sm8181-4-2016). Stud. Math. 233 (2016), 209–226.